# How to temporarily disable JRE on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, java

I'm looking to disable/re-enable the JRE on OSX Mountain Lion for some development testing purpose without need to uninstall it. I think it was able to do still OSX Lion. But in Mountain Lion, I can't find any solutions for this. I want to disable the whole JRE. Not just applet in browser.

Edit:
In the latest OSX version (Mountain Lion), JRE is removed by Apple. So disable from Java preference panel is no-more available. I want to disable it on Mountain Lion.

Comment: how was it done in OSX Lion?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Java Preferences** program, which should be located in `/Applications/Utilities/`:

[image]

On the "General" page, uncheck all the JREs

[image]

It's still *possible* to run Java like this, if you fiddle on the command line.  Likewise, if you've installed Java in a non-Mac way, this won't help you.  But this should break all normal Java usage on your computer until you re-activate a JRE.

Comment: In latest OSX version, Mountain Lion, JRE is removed by Apple. So Java preference panel is also removed. I want to disable it on Mountain Lion. So this method is no more available on lates Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

In Mountain Lion...

**Java 7**

If you have installed the Java 7 JRE provided by Oracle...
A Java preferences icon will be installed in `System Preferences`

[image: http://i.imgur.com/PRuiLb2.png]

When clicking on it... a separate Java control panel will launch.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8lu9Euv.png]

Click the `Security` tab... and you should be able to check/uncheck the "Enable Java content in the browser"

...

**Java 6**

Otherwise... if you're using the regular Java 6 library... as the `root` user... you may have to physically move the plugin out of the following directories:

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/`

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java/`